# SFDX Community create command is not working with template

Tags: salesforcedx, community-cloud, experience-cloud, experience-bundle

I am trying to create a community with B2B Commerce template, but command is throwing error, I tried escape double quotes as well but getting the same error. Looks like I am unable to pass the proper spaces.

```
storename='"Cap Store"'
b2btemplate='"B2B Commerce"'
tempdescription='"Store created by CLI"'
cmd="sfdx force:community:create --name $storename --templatename $b2btemplate --targetusername abc@abbc.com --urlpathprefix default --description $tempdescription"
coutput=$($cmd)
```

### OUTPUT

```
$ bash temp.sh
ERROR running force:community:create: The following varargs were invalid or unsupported: Store"="undefined" Commerce"="undefined" created="undefined" by="undefined" CLI"="undefined"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to reproduce it and it's working fine.
I hope you've got this issue resolved by now. If not, let me know the details.

I tried this command,

```
storename='"Cap Store"'
b2btemplate='"B2B Commerce"'
tempdescription='"Store created by CLI"'
orgalias = "my-org-alias"
cmd="sfdx force:community:create --name $storename --templatename $b2btemplate --urlpathprefix default --description $tempdescription -u $orgalias"
eval ${cmd}
```